# Счетчик просмотра страницы

Tags: mysql, php, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, как сделать счетчик просмотра страницы?
Есть сайт с заявками, и нужно вывести, сколько раз ту или иную заявку просматривали. Вроде бы все просто: при создании заявки писать в таблице БД значение 0 (ноль), а при просмотре вытаскивать это значение, увеличивать на единицу и записывать обратно в БД.
Но что-то меня терзают сомнения, а правильное ли это решение?
А также как избавиться от "накрутки" при обновлении страницы?

Comment: А может, традиционно, Яндекс.Метрика?

Comment: Причем тут Яндекс Метрика? Прочитайте внимательно вопрос и подумайте, что я хочу сделать.

Comment: @Batyabest при том, что она решает поставленные проблемы.

Comment: Мне нужно вывести на сайте: заявку просматривали 1258 раз. Это можно сделать метрикой? Скажите как?

Comment: А я жду, когда мне подскажут, как это сделать с помощью метрики - она же "решает поставленные проблемы"...

Comment: @Batyabest Метрика решает только в части сбора данных и отчётов, видных владельцам.

Отображать данные по каждой странице посетителям — только неимоверными костылями, увы.

Comment: Ну так люди кричат, что можно. ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При загрузке страницы отправляйте в базу запрос типа

```
UPDATE `table` SET `views`=`views`+1 WHERE `page`='$pageId';
```

после чего

```
SELECT `views` FROM `table` WHERE `page`='$pageId'
```

и выводите результат второго запроса пользователям.

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы не накручивали просмотры, нужно создать дополнительную таблицу с логом, в котором будут данные страница/ip, и проверять перед записью, существует ли такой ip на данной странице.

Для динамических айпишников нужно в сессию заносить данные. А лучше и то, и другое делать одновременно.

Comment: Можно поподробнее про сессию?

Answer (score 0):

[[@Batyabest](/users/22866/batyabest)](/users/22866/batyabest)
а что подробнее? гугла нет?

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['somevalue'])){
echo 'Не будем что то делать';
}else{
echo 'Будем что то делать';
}
?>
```

Вот она, логическая конструкция для вас. 
Занести значение в сессии то же самое, что присвоить значение переменной:

```
$_SESSION['somevalue'] = 123;
```

С массивом $_SESSION работают так же, как и с другим массивом.

Answer (score 0):

I. Надо идентифицировать посетителя. По кукам, если поддерживаются. Если нет – по ip и сигнатуре браузера.

II. Данные о том, *какие* заявки просмотрены каждым клиентом, – и *когда*, если допускаете более одного просмотра заявки посетителем, когда между просмотрами прошло больше X часов – можно хранить либо у клиента (в куках), либо у себя в БД.

III. Счётчики просмотров заявок храним у себя в БД.

Как поступить в п. II, зависит от кол-ва заявок и того, будут ли пытаться «злодеи» накрутить, или это, если и возможно, то только случайно, при обновлении страницы, например.

При большой посещаемости сайта можно снять нагрузку счётчика с php. Веб-сервер будет писать в логи посещения необходимую инфу (User-Agent, ip, значение кук, если присутствуют), и тогда достаточно раз в X минут анализировать лог скриптом, который будет вытаскивать оттуда данные о просмотрах и обновлять БД.

Comment: Это все сложно и запутанно, мне нужен просто скрипт, который будет собирать и выводить нужные цифры.

Comment: просто скрипт напишут на фриланс-бирже на копейки. Здесь помогают понять, как сделать самостоятельно.

Comment: Я сам напишу без проблем, мне нужен был небольшой совет. Всем спасибо.